# How to fetch only a single record of data from a fake public api in angular using observable?

Tags: http, service, observable, angular9, angular10

I'm using json placeholder fake api
(https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users).
I need the code (service file and ts file) to get only single record of data.I already fetched the all data from api..
Please help me....I am a beginner in angular

Answer (score 1):

use this
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1
for 1st id
or
`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`
for dynamic